# What's the name of a device to simulate an object jumping in the air?

Tags: springs, coil-spring

I want to make a film of a puppet jumping in the air into the water of a lagoon. I am looking for a pad with a spring release timer that I can bury in the sand so it's out of sight from the camera, wait 10 seconds for example, and the spring or coil releases and throws the puppet in the air, making it look like the puppet jumping with its legs. The mechanism is similar to ["jack-in-the-box"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack-in-the-box) and all I can find is the fast-food restaurant. I have also found no relevant results with "spring with delay", "spring release with pad", and "spring release with timer".

What is the name of such a device?

**Update**: Here's a drawing for what I want to achieve:

[image: drawing for jack-in-the-box mechanism]

I am looking for the name of the complete mechanism, including the pad for launching and the release timer.

Comment: If the object or puppet is actually to be propelled through the air it is **not** a simulation.

Comment: @Solar Mike Yes, it is. To simulate something means to imitate the process in some way. If you want to see/film the puppet *jumping into the lake under its own power* you can't.  So you simulate a jumping puppet by launching an inanimate puppet into the lake using some apparatus.

Comment: Try "spring release mechanism" or "spring loaded release mechanism".

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I searched for these terms, with and without "pad" as a extra term, and could not find a relevant one. The closest I imagined was a foot pump with a hook holding it in place (and then I need to devise a way to release the hook).

Answer (score 1):

Try trigger release or catch release or latch mechanism.

But why not use a compressed air jet - the control can be with you, just needs a tube and support.

Comment: I am looking for the name of the full mechanism, if any, and so I added a drawing and a clarification.

Comment: I searched again for these terms and could not find a relevant mechanism. Compressed air jet is complicated if I need a compressor, as this will be filmed in nature.